# Convert textarea text to upper case ondblclick using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Having one of those moments, why doesn't the below example work? When the user double clicks in the textarea, I want the text to be converted to upper case.

```html
<textarea id="property_summary" name="property_summary" rows="5" cols="70" class="countcharacters" data-limit="1000" data-report="summary_cc" ondblclick="property_summary.value.toUpperCase();" required>This is test text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`property_summary.value.toUpperCase()` is not an assignment.

Try

```
this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set the value like so: `this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();`

```html
<textarea id="property_summary" name="property_summary" rows="5" cols="70" class="countcharacters" data-limit="1000" data-report="summary_cc" ondblclick="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" required>This is test text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ondblclick="property_summary.value.toUpperCase();"` isn't changing the content of the textarea. Rather, set the value of the textarea by setting the `value` of `this`, because `this` represents the textarea in this context.

Thus, to fix this problem, simply set `ondblclick="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"`.

```html
<textarea ondblclick="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">This is test text</textarea>
```